# yum install Puppet 4.x on a CentOS 6 machine

Tags: puppet, centos6, yum

I have a machine running CentOS 6.6 and I want to install Puppet 4.x on it. 
I followed the instructions on the documentation page and I installed the Puppet repository first:

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-6.noarch.rpm
```

Whatever I try to install via yum (puppet server or puppet agent) it offers me puppet version 3.8.7.
But I see on the Puppet official website that latest Puppet is 4.4. I read the documentation but I couldn't find a way to install this version via yum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Puppet 4, you need the PC1 (Puppet Collections) repositories instead of the older one you've configured.

For CentOS/EL 6, run:

```
rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-el-6.noarch.rpm
```

This configures a repo that contains a `puppet-agent` package, containing Puppet 4 and other tools.

See [Using Puppet Collections](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html) and [Welcome to Puppet Collections](https://puppet.com/blog/welcome-to-puppet-collections) for more details.

Comment: Right. The link you provided is clearly specified in the documentation but I missed it. Thanks, it works now!

Comment: A lot of time has passed, The answer is still valid. The links are dead.